# Swift: how to fetch objects made today from parse?

Tags: swift, datetime, parse-platform

I'm a Beginner so please be friendly while explaining, Thanks.

So basically i'm trying to fetch objects made today using createdAt.

```
     let parseQuery = PFQuery(className: "request")

    parseQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects {

            for object in objects {

                    self.reqDates.append(object.createdAt!)
            }
        }
    }

            let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
            let formatteddate = formatter.stringFromDate(self.reqDates[indexPath.row])
            myCell.reqDate.text = formatteddate
```

When i do this fetch it shows me all objects with their dates correctly. But how can i display objects of today only not all of them created.
I hope i explained good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request object where `createdAt` is greater than today (midnight)

```
 let parseQuery = PFQuery(className: "request")

            let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
            let components = cal.components([.Day , .Month, .Year ], fromDate: NSDate())
            let todayDate = cal.dateFromComponents(components)

            parseQuery.whereKey("createdAt", greaterThan:todayDate!)

            parseQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
                if let objects = objects {

                    for object in objects {
                        print(object.createdAt)
                    }
                }
            }
```